# Rows results to columns in MySQL Query (prestashop)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, prestashop

I'm trying to create a MySQL query that will list the products attributes on Prestashop together in a single row (I don't want to depend on paid modules).

The current query is:

```
SELECT
p.id_product AS 'idProduto',
pac.id_attribute,
al.name 'Nome_SKU',
pa.id_product_attribute as 'idSKU',
pl.name AS 'Nome',
pl.description_short AS 'Descricao Curta',
pl.description AS 'Descricao',
pl.meta_title AS 'Meta-Title',
pl.meta_keywords AS 'Meta-keyword',
pl.meta_description AS 'meta-description',
pl.link_rewrite AS 'URL rewrite',
pl.available_now AS 'texto_estoque',
pl.available_later AS 'texto_indisponivel',
pa.quantity as 'Quantidade',
p.price 'Preco',
pa.minimal_quantity 'Quantidade Minima',
p.active AS 'Ativo (0/1)'

FROM 
ps_product p 

INNER JOIN
ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product 

INNER JOIN
ps_product_attribute pa ON pl.id_product = pa.id_product 

INNER JOIN
ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON pa.id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute 

INNER JOIN
ps_attribute_lang al ON al.id_attribute = pac.id_attribute 

where pl.id_lang = 6
AND p.id_product = 101

group by pa.id_product_attribute,al.name
```

And it's results are like this (i.e. id_product 101):

[image]

What I need is the results to "group" in a same row by their idSKU to show the values (Nome_SKU) each in one column, beeing like this (i.e. idSKU 647):

[image]

Comment: Replace ALL the inverted commas (') with back ticks (`)

Comment: search from GROUP_CONCAT + GROUP BY

Comment: i already tried those solutions, but the group concat will only concatenate all results into one field. Can someone help me edit the current query ?

Comment: You cant do what you want, at least not with a single row by the idSKU  because there is differents idSKU on your first query it shows 647, 649 at least theese two will come.

Comment: I'm Sorry Jorge, but it is possible. i Saw someting like making a Select inside a select field. (this in SQL, of course).